# Super Contest Time Frame

Tags: support, superuser-blog, super-contest

Quoting [the announcement blog post](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/08/19/super-users-2nd-birthday-super-contest/) from August 19th:

> This contest will be going on for the next two weeks starting Monday the 29th at 00:00 UTC!

The 29th was five days ago.

<sup>The announcement both stated *next two weeks* and *August 29th*, which doesn't match. But still, exact date and time (*and time zone*) trumps the rest of the sentence IMO.</sup>

---

Today, on the SU home page:

> The Super User 2nd anniversary contest ends Sunday! Cast your final vote for the Most Valuable Super User and submit your blog posts now.

This is tomorrow.

---

This might have been the shortest two weeks I have ever experienced. This will be a surprise for folks aiming for the prizes, for example, I can imagine more blog posts coming next week.

Comment: I went ahead and killed that message for now.

Comment: Oh dear. This seems to be a rather serious typo... it should have read "Monday the 19th". As you can see, the 29th was not even a Monday. I'm not really sure what we should do here... the contest was announced as "starting" on the site on the 19th and was posted then, and we saw a corresponding increase in activity. So do we continue the contest with the incorrectly posted dates, or end it at the intended scheduled time?

Comment: @nhinkle Your calendar shows September already. This refers to August when 22nd and 29th were Mondays.

Comment: @DanielBeck: oh, right. Correct. It seems we just put the wrong data in the blog post.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Those who found out about this from the blog, and started 7 days late, will certainly be disadvantaged.  But they'll still be disadvantaged if the contest is extended, since those who started on time will also have the extra week.

I say end the contest on time, and apologize for being human.  There's no way to accurately determine who was disadvantaged, so there's no way to appropriately compensate them.

Comment: This seems like the best course of action. I will update the blog post to reflect this, and will reinstate the message. FWIW, they've only missed 7 days - the contest started on Monday the 22nd.

Comment: @nhinkle: Not necessarily, given that the announcement message changed at the start.

Comment: @Tom well what's done is done, unfortunately.

Comment: @nhinkle: I don't see the problem, daily visitors did see the message that announced it has started.

Comment: @Tom so we agree then? The contest ended when it was originally intended to, and most people already saw the message, as you said.

Comment: @nhinkle: My first comment reflected "they've only missed 7 days".

Comment: @Tom oh I see what you mean. Yes. I guess I should have said "at most" 7 days. Most people were aware of the full extent of the contest, as I mentioned in my comment on the question.